# How to merge two addEventListener to single one click?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

[todo list app preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuryP.png)

I have two addEventListener, the one is to change the text color and the other one to change the circle color.

Condition 1:
When I clicked the circle, both of text and circle color was changed.

Condition 2:
The problem was when **I clicked the text**, its color was changed, but **the circle didn't change**.

So can I merge it into just only one addEventListener at the circle? and disable click for the text? Or can I make the text work like I clicked the circle? 
[Github Link](https://github.com/rheriprasetyo/todo-list-app) 
[Preview](https://rheriprasetyo.github.io/todo-list-app/)

```
let lists = document.querySelectorAll(".list-item");
let circles = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-circle");

// Click the text
Array.from(lists).forEach((list) => {
  list.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
    list.classList.add("done");
  });
});

// Click the circle
Array.from(circles).forEach((circle) => {
  circle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
    circle.classList.remove("fa-regular");
    circle.classList.add("fa-solid", "fa-circle-check");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you? Yes. How? Post your "*[mcve]*" code, and we might be able to offer advice. Without your relevant HTML (and possibly CSS) it's hard to make any recommendations.

Comment: @DavidThomas sure, I've posted the source code on Github. [github](https://github.com/rheriprasetyo/todo-list-app) [preview](https://rheriprasetyo.github.io/todo-list-app/)

Comment: But not in your question, where it needs to be. A question should be self-contained so that we can still understand and answer, even if the rest of the internet falls over somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want. By the way, what does your DOM tree look like? is `.list-item` a parent of/ or a sibling to '.fa-circle'?. If you want to dispatch the event once the user clicks anywhere on a list item. Then you can use the parent, like this:

```js
const listParents = document.querySelectorAll('.list-parent')

function handleItemClick(event) {
  const listParent = event.target
  
  const listText = listParent.querySelector('.list-item')
  const listCircle = listParent.querySelector('.list-circle')
  
  listText.classList.toggle('done')

  listCircle.classList.toggle('fa-circle')
  listCircle.classList.toggle('fa-regular')
  
  listCircle.classList.toggle('fa-circle-check')
  listCircle.classList.toggle('fa-solid')


  l 
}

Array.from(listParents).forEach(listParent => {
  listParent.addEventListener('click', handleItemClick)
})
```